# Python; When trying to convert an image to a numpy array of type float I get "ValueError; setting an array element with a sequence."

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I am reading a bunch of images with opencv in python like so:

```
data = []
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)
```

so data contains an array of numpy arrays. I would now like to convert it all to float and then divide by 255 like so:

```
data = np.array(data, dtype='float') / 255.0
```

But I get the error `ValueError; setting an array element with a sequence`

Does this mean that there are some values in `data` that are not convertible to float? Does `img_to_array` sometimes return non-number values?

Comment: Do all the images have the same dimensions?

Comment: No, what happens to the array when an image is bigger/smaller?

Comment: You don't, numpy is constructed to work with arrays where the dimensions are all fixed. So you probably better first add some extra pixels to the smaller ones such that these grow to the same size.

Comment: What is `img_to_array`?

Comment: oops forgot to mention `image_to_array` is from keras.preprocessing.image library

Thanks @WillemVanOnsem, resizing the images fixed the issue!